# CPI data in python, create a dataframe

Tags: python, for-loop, datetime

I am fairly new to python and I am trying to create a data frame with all the CPI data in it.

Nonetheless I do not manage to increase the month in the function.

Can anybody help?

\>import cpi

\>from datetime import date

\>cpi.get(date(2022, 11, 1))

\>n = 12

I suppose it should be something like this:

```
for i in range(n):
    cpi.get(date(2022,n+1,1)
```

But no idea how to increase this and put into a dataframe.

Comment: This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask], [mre] and the other links found on those pages.

Comment: [Pandas user guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/index.html).

Comment: You need to create a function to get the the values you want from the cpi module, after you return a value from that function and pass it to a pandas dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(myfunction(value))

Comment: `cpi.get()` - you at least need save the return value of each call, maybe in a list, maybe in a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

For a single year's worth of data:

```
import cpi
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd

date_list = []
cpi_list = []
for i in range(12):
    date_list.append(dt.date(2022, i + 1, 1)) # i + 1 to avoid 0 value
    cpi_list.append(cpi.get(date_list[i]))

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': date_list, 'CPI': cpi_list})
```

Hope that helps,

--K

Comment: I have tried this, but it gives the following error: Index of monthly type for 2022-12-01 does not exist do I miss some library?

Comment: solved, it cannot be 12 as the December CPI data has not been released yet